# Code inspection says I need to dispose object. Which one?

Tags: c#, code-inspection

This is my function. I already wrapped both client and message into using clause and still get error when run code inspection. Error points to first using line:

```
public static void Send(MailItem mail)
        {
            var sender = Membership.GetUser(mail.CreatedBy);
            if (sender == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            using (var msg = new MailMessage { From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailSender"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailSenderName"]) })
            {
                foreach (var recipient in mail.MailRecipients)
                {
                    var recipientX = Membership.GetUser(recipient.UserKey);
                    if (recipientX == null)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(recipientX.Email, recipientX.UserName));
                }

                msg.Subject = "[From: " + sender.UserName + "]" + mail.Subject;
                msg.Body = mail.Body;

                if (HttpContext.Current != null)
                {
                    msg.Body += Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "To reply via Web click link below:" +
                                Environment.NewLine;
                    msg.Body += ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailPagePath"] + "?AID=" +
                                ContextManager.CurrentAccount.AccountId + "&RUN=" + sender.UserName;
                }

                try
                {
                    using (var emailClient = new SmtpClient())
                    {
                        emailClient.Send(msg);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Logger.LogException(ex);
                }
            }
        }
```

This is warning I get:

> Warning   1   CA2000 :
>   Microsoft.Reliability : In method
>   'Email.Send(MailItem)', object
>   '<>g_*initLocal0' is not disposed
>   along all exception paths. Call
>   System.IDisposable.Dispose on object
>   '<>g*_initLocal0' before all
>   references to it are out of
>   scope.    C:\CodeWorkspace\Code\Utility\Email.cs  41

Comment: Well what is at line 41 in your code?

Comment: @BrokenGlass: What *is* at line 41 in his code?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Impossible to say considering this is only part of the code within the file.

Comment: I said in my post that error points to the first "using" line

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
using (var msg = new MailMessage { From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailSender"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailSenderName"]) })
```

The initializer block `{ From = ... }` is executed after the object is constructed and before the `using` block's internal `try/finally` begins.

If the `MailAddress` constructor (or its argument expressions, or the assignment to `From` if it is a property accessor) throws an exception, the `MailMessage` will not be disposed.

Change to:

```
using (var msg = new MailMessage()) 
{
    msg.From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailSender"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailSenderName"]);
    ...
}
```

The temporary `<>g_initLocal0` variable is the name of the MailMessage before it gets assigned to `msg`.

Comment: Moved creation of "From" inside block and voila!

Comment: I've encountered this before with different objects but similiar circumstances.  Set the MailAddress after the MailMessage has been constructed.